# update the data base from this model using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I’m having following Ajax function in my View.

function Save() {

```
    var Url = '@Url.Action("UpdateCaseDetails", "CaseDetailView")';
    var frm = $("form");
    var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { models: data },
        async: false,
        cache:true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

My control has this code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateCaseDetails(string models)
        {
            string errorMsg = string.Empty;
            string successMsg = string.Empty;
            string testModel = models;
            CaseDetailViewModel obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaseDetailViewModel>(testModel);
            successMsg = "Case update successfully";
            return Json(new { success = true, message = successMsg });
        }
```

I need to update the data base from this model using Ajax. After posting the view using form.serializeArray() method it posts following json string.

```
[{"name":"CaseAction","value":"10"},{"name":"CaseHoldsFor","value":"0"},
{"name":"CaseHoldUntil","value":"0001-01-01"},
{"name":"CaseOfficerAssigned","value":""},
{"name":"CaseDateToLegal","value":"0001-01-01 12:00:00 AM"},
{"name":"CaseDateToCourt","value":"0001-01-01"},
{"name":"CaseCourtCaseNo","value":" "},
{"name":"CaseDateHere","value":"0001-01-01"}]
```

But after hitting this code it gives following error.

```
CaseDetailViewModel obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaseDetailViewModel>(testModel);
```

Error Details:

```
    Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'RAMIS.Collection.BusinessEntity.Models.CaseDetailViewModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. 
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object 
(e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

I tried following way also.

```
CaseDetailViewModel objResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaseDetailViewModel>(testModel.Substring(1, testModel.Length - 2));
```

But it does not work for me. Please give me a solution for this

Edit:

My Model class as follows:

```
public class CaseDetailViewModel
    {            
        [DataMember]
        public string Tin { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public string CaseID { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public string CaseType { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public string CaseStatus { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public string CaseTaxType { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? CaseTaxPeriodBegin { get; set; }            
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? CaseTaxPeriodEnd { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? CaseCreationDate { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public decimal? CaseBalance { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public string CaseOfficerAssigned { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? CaseDateAssigned { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public int CaseAgeofCase { get; set; }    
        [DataMember]
        public string CaseCustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting back a string and not `IEnumerable<yourModel>`? Show you model and the view.

Comment: You have not shown the view, but if your doing it correctly using strongly typed html helpers - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tin)` etc. Then all you need to do is `data: frm.serialize()` in the ajax method and change you POST method to `public ActionResult UpdateCaseDetails(CaseDetailViewModel model)` - the framework will take care of the binding for you.

Comment: Although it looks like you are only posting back some properties of your model so you really should be using a view model containing only those properties you need to display/edit in the view.

Answer (score 0):

As your json data is array of an key-value pair, you might need to deserialize this json data into dictionary of key vaue pair as below.

```
var yourDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(testModel);;
//then you need to write some logic to get values from dictionary and convert it into your object of CaseDetailViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the entity CaseDetailViewModel you need to create a structure equals to CaseDetailViewModel on javascript and serialice it.

```
var struct = [];
struct.push (new Object ({
Tin: ""
CaseID: ""
CaseType: ""
CaseStatus: ""
CaseTaxType: ""
CaseTaxPeriodBegin: null,
CaseTaxPeriodEnd: null,
CaseCreationDate: null,
CaseBalance: null,
CaseOfficerAssigned: ""
CaseDateAssigned: null,
CaseAgeofCase: 1,
CaseCustomerName: ""
}));
jQuery.ajax ({
url: ""
type: "post"
asyn: true,
dataType: "json"
data: {vm: JSON.stringify (struct)}});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateCaseDetails (string vm)
{
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <IEnumerable<CaseDetailViewModel>> (vm);
}
```

Edit:
If you only need work with one object:

```
var struct = new Object(..... complete object
```

and

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <CaseDetailViewModel>(vm);
```